# Bootstrap class offset, isn't working

Tags: class, offset

I'm using bootstrap latest version 4.1.0. Bootstrap offset class isn't working properly in any screen size as expected. "Strange". Nothing changed. Please help me to get out of it. Here it is....

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">

            <div class="cus_c">Content area</div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">

            <div class="cus_c">Content area</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to bootstrap 4, there is a change. Change `col-md-offset-3` to `offset-md-3`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to center the columns you can use justify-content-center class on the containing row

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-md-3">

            <div class="cus_c">Content area</div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">

            <div class="cus_c">Content area</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mcgraw/pen/6b11392deb8b7124384ba6b3fa17daca)

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap latest **version: 4.1.0** there is a simple update.

Use this class **offset-md**-* instead of **md-offset**-*

Thank you.